# Windows Driver Verifier Options with Special Pool for my disk filter driver, When shutdown windows,It become Gray Screen

Tags: windows, driver, verify

It is hard to explain the question,I write two driver,a Disk filter driver and volume filter driver,When I don't open verfier.exe to verify speical pool for my driver.Every thing is Ok.But when I open it ,the window can't shutdown ,it become gray screen.It only for disk driver,not for volume driver.

I debug it with windbg,I found when System send down a Irp(IRP_MN_DEVICE_USAGE_NOTIFICATION) to my driver,I analyze it,if this irp's Parameters.UsageNotification.Type is not DeviceUsageTypePaging,I pass through it,but it did't return ,it's blocking; 
IRP_MN_DEVICE_USAGE_NOTIFICATION do fun:

```
case IRP_MN_DEVICE_USAGE_NOTIFICATION:
    {
        BOOLEAN setPagable;

        if (pIrpStack->Parameters.UsageNotification.Type != DeviceUsageTypePaging) 
        {
            status = pOSNDf->PassThroughIrp(pOSNDiskDevice->GetTargetDeviceObject(), 
                pIrp);
            COSNDf::MyReleaseRemoveLock(pOSNDiskDevice->GetRemoveLock(),pIrp);

            return status;
        }

        //
        // wait on the paging path event
        //

        status = KeWaitForSingleObject(&pOSNDiskDevice->PagingPathCountEvent,
            Executive, 
            KernelMode,
            FALSE, 
            NULL);

        //
        // if removing last paging device, need to set DO_POWER_PAGABLE
        // bit here, and possible re-set it below on failure.
        //

        setPagable = FALSE;
        if (!pIrpStack->Parameters.UsageNotification.InPath &&
            pOSNDiskDevice->PagingPathCount == 1 ) 
        {
            //
            // removing the last paging file
            // must have DO_POWER_PAGABLE bits set
            //

            if (pDeviceObject->Flags & DO_POWER_INRUSH) {
            } else {
                pDeviceObject->Flags |= DO_POWER_PAGABLE;
                setPagable = TRUE;
            }
        }

        //
        // send the irp synchronously
        //

        status = pOSNDf->SynchorousSendPnPIrpDown(pOSNDiskDevice->GetTargetDeviceObject(), pIrp);

        //
        // now deal with the failure and success cases.
        // note that we are not allowed to fail the irp
        // once it is sent to the lower drivers.
        //

        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) 
        {
            IoAdjustPagingPathCount(
                &pOSNDiskDevice->PagingPathCount,
                pIrpStack->Parameters.UsageNotification.InPath);

            if (pIrpStack->Parameters.UsageNotification.InPath)
            {
                if (pOSNDiskDevice->PagingPathCount == 1) 
                {
                    pDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_POWER_PAGABLE;
                }
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            //
            // cleanup the changes done above
            //

            if (setPagable == TRUE) 
            {
                pDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_POWER_PAGABLE;
                setPagable = FALSE;
            }
        }

        //
        // set the event so the next one can occur.
        //

        KeSetEvent(&pOSNDiskDevice->PagingPathCountEvent,
            IO_NO_INCREMENT, FALSE);

        //
        // and complete the irp
        //

        IoCompleteRequest(pIrp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

        COSNDf::MyReleaseRemoveLock(pOSNDiskDevice->GetRemoveLock(),pIrp);

        return status;


    }

PassThroughIrp fun code;
NTSTATUS COSNDf::PassThroughIrp(PDEVICE_OBJECT  pDeviceObject,PIRP pIrp)
{
    IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);
    return IoCallDriver(pDeviceObject, pIrp);
}
```

I debug it ,the pIrpStack->Parameters.UsageNotification.Type is DeviceUsageTypeDumpFile; and when the call iocalldriver this irp ,the blocking system function is nt!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListResume,it always loop;can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for everybody.I solve this problem .I look up msdn ,find when the type is DeviceUsageTypeDumpFile,before passthrough this irp ,we need clear the DO_Power_Page flag,if you open the verifier,it work strict with it;